# Dropdown menu in React, filter through list

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, jsx

I am building a rest countries app in react and I'm trying to filter by region through a list. I would like to use a dropdown menu. I have tried using react select, creating a new component, this is my code

```
const DropdownMenu = (props) => {
    const options = [
        '', 'Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'
      ];
    const defaultOption = options[0];

    const handleFilterInput = (event) => {
        let value = event.target.options;
        props.handleRegionSearch(value);  
    };

    return(
        <div>
            <Select options={options} onChange={handleFilterInput} value={defaultOption} placeholder="Select a region"/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DropdownMenu;
```

My problem is, I can not get the value to change to the option selected, therefore it's impossible for me to filter the list I took from the api.
Does anyone have a possible solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the value wrong

```
value={defaultOption}
```

This default option is never changing.

What you can do is catch the current value from onChange() and set the value somewhere (preferably in state) and then use that stored value as the value of dropdown component

Something like this.

```
    const options = [
        '', 'Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'
      ];

    const [selectedValue , setSelectedValue ] = useState(options[0]);

    const handleFilterInput = (event) => {
        let value = event.target.options;
        setSelectedValue(value);
        props.handleRegionSearch(value);  
    };

    return(
        <div>
            <Select options={options} onChange={handleFilterInput} value={selectedValue} placeholder="Select a region"/>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.
However after applying your suggestions, my dropdown menu doesn't display the options when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! In the end, I used a *react-select* component which did solve a this issue on it's own.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).